# Is there a way I can get D3 to iterate through my data collection, plotting point by point?

Tags: d3.js

new to d3 but have made it to the stage of loading data from a csv file and visualising it using svg elements:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {         
csvData = data;                         
    svg.selectAll("circle")             
                    .data(csvData)
                    .enter()      
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.LocationX})  
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.LocationY})  
                    .attr("r", 10)                                          
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("fill", "orange")

        })
```

Obviously, all my data points are plotted simultaneously. Is there an efficient way of using D3 functions to "build" the plot point by point? Can't find an example to follow.

Comment: Hope that now conforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d3 enter() is adding all of the elements in the csvData array at one time. You can build the graph up one point at a time by starting with an empty array, pushing elements from csvData (i.e. points) into it one at a time then running the

```
  svg.selectAll("circle")             
    .data(NewArray)
    .enter()      
    .append("circle")
```

on this new array each time a new point is added.

Here is a working example https://bl.ocks.org/AndrewStaroscik/7371301 using a setInterval that is cleared once all the points are added.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate this by adding the circles with radius 0 and then increasing it with a transition (which you can, but don't have to, animate). The code would look like this.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")             
                .data(csvData)
                .enter()      
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.LocationX})  
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.LocationY})       
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("fill", "orange")
                .attr("r", 0)
                .transition().duration(0)
                .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 500; })
                .attr("r", 10);
```

This creates the circles with radius 0 and then adds a transition with a delay that increases with the index of the circle which increases the radius to 10. That is, initially there will be one circle visible, after 500ms 2, after 1s 3 and so on. You can obviously customise this interval.

To clarify, all the DOM elements will be created at the start, you're only changing the attributes such that it will seem that they are appearing one after the other. The advantage of doing it this way is that it fits nicely with the rest of the D3 functionality and you don't have to resort to anything else to separate your data.